# Recommended use for Joda-Time's DateMidnight

Tags: java, date, jodatime

The javdoc for `LocalDate#toDateMidnight` reads as follows:

> As from v1.5, you are recommended to avoid DateMidnight and use
>   toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() instead because of the exception detailed
>   below.
>
> This method will throw an exception if the default time zone switches
>   to Daylight Savings Time at midnight and this LocalDate represents
>   that switchover date. The problem is that there is no such time as
>   midnight on the required date, and as such an exception is thrown.

The fact that midnight does not exist in certain time zones seems like reason enough to avoid using `DateMidnight` entirely (assuming your code is not using a fixed time zone that is known not to have this DST situation and will never need to use different time zones in the future).

However, `DateMidnight` is not deprecated and there is no similar recommendation or warning in the javadoc for the `DateMidnight` class itself.  Furthermore, the `DateMidnight` constructor happily accepts an instant and time zone such that midnight does not exist on the given day, rather than throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` like `LocalDate#toDateMidnight`.  The resulting `DateMidnight` behaves like a `DateTime` with time at start of day.

When midnight does not exist on a given day, why does `LocalDate#toDateMidnight` throw an exception while the `DateMidnight` constructor does not?  What is the recommended use case for `DateMidnight` if any?

Comment: Note that the “midnight” related classes and methods were indeed deprecated in a later update to Joda-Time 2.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no good reason to use `DateMidnight`. `LocalDate` is the better option. Thats because midnight does not occur once a year in certain time-zones, completely messing up the usability of the class, and creating bugs in applications.

The constructor was fixed to avoid the worst problem, however seeing a `DateMidnight` object with the internal millisecond value pointing at 01:00 isn't exactly great.

Comment: Once a year should probably be once a day?

Comment: No. I mean once a year in Spring, when DST skips from 23:59 to 01:00.

Comment: Which timezones?  I know in the US, DST changes occur at 2 am.

Comment: Asia/Gaza for example

Comment: OMG. I was always wondering what could be invented by humanity stupider than changing the clocks mandatory twice a year. And here it is - change them exactly after 23:59:59 skipping the midnight.

Answer (score 38):

new DateTime().[withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) is recommended.

Comment: Actually not just recommended. All of the “midnight” related classes and methods in Joda-Time have been deprecated with an explanation that they are based on a faulty concept. You absolutely should be using `withTimeAtStartOfDay` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Or better use the `LocalDate` method [`toDateTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) directly to bypass creation of `DateTime` object (in relation to [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586395/1768232)).

```
new LocalDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay( myDateTimeZone )
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, specifically [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) instead of the slippery idea of “midnight”.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // A time zone.
ZonedDateTime todayStart = LocalDate.now( z ).atStartOfDay( z );  // Produces a LocalDate (a whole day without time zone), then transforms into a `ZonedDateTime` (a moment on the timeline)
```

## java.time

Since the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and the team advises migration to the java.time classes, I will add example using java.time.

If you want to represent the entire day as a whole, use the `LocalDate` class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

As discussed on this page, trying to pinpoint the end of the day is poor practice. For one thing, you have the problem of an infinitely divisible fraction for that last second of the day. Do you resolve to milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, or something else, as all of these are in common use? Instead use the first moment of the new day.

Let java.time determine the wall-clock time of that first moment of the day. Do not assume the time will be `00:00:00` as anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may mean the first moment is a time such as `01:00:00`. Such DST adjustments are currently use in time zones of multiple countries.

So, to get a moment, an actual point on the timeline, for the start of the day call `LocalDate::atStartOfDay`. Notice this is a shorter version of the method name than used in Joda-Time’s `withTimeAtStartOfDay` method. Specify the desired/expected time zone in a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z );
```

### Half-Open

So how to represent a span of time? If I want to pinpoint the the beginning and ending of this single day, how do I do that while also following this advice? The solution commonly used in date-time work is the Half-Open approach. In this approach, the beginning of the span is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So “today” means starting with the first moment of the day and running all the way up to, but *not* including, the first moment of the following day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartToday = LocalDate.now( z ).atStartOfDay( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStartTomorrow = zdtStartToday.plusDays( 1 );
```

By the way, the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project has a handy [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class for such spans of time.

```
Interval todayInterval = Interval.of( 
        zdtStartToday.toInstant() ,
        zdtStartTomorrow.toInstant()
    )
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exception i had in my code

```
Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 2015-03-27T00:00:00.000 (Asia/Amman)
    org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 2015-03-27T00:00:00.000 (Asia/Amman)
```

Now i solved it by using

```
LocalDate currentDate=new LocalDate();
someMethodSetsTheDate(currentDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate());
```

Instead of

```
someMethodSetsTheDate(new DateMidnight(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear(), date.getDayOfMonth()).toDate());
```

Now my recommendation is to use 
**.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()**
to avoid similar exceptions .

Please Feel Free To Edit My Answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here a more simple solution that will check if the dateTime occurs at midnight **local time**

```
private boolean isAtMidnight(org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime) {
   return dateTime.toLocalDateTime().getMillisOfDay() == 0;
}
```